# Receiver type for instance message does not declare a method with selector

Tags: objective-c

I'm only new to this and not sure if i have to define rotate, if I'm just making an error or just doing the wrong thing in general.

Here's what i have so far:

```
- (IBAction)TestDrive:(id)sender {                    
    CGPoint center = CGPointMake(car.center.x,
    self.view.frame.origin.y + car.frame.size.height/2);
    [UIView animateWithDuration:3 animations:^{
        car.center = center;
    } 
     completion:^(BOOL finished){
    [self rotate]; //error here
    }];
}

- (void)rotate;{
    }

- (void)returnCar; {
    }

- (void)continueRotation;{
    }

@end
```

Comment: You must post the exact and complete error message. If you ever ask a question about an error, you must also include that error.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are using the latest LLVM compiler (and maybe turn on a particular option), the compiler will warn if it hasn't yet seen the declaration of a method when that method is called.   Since the compiler does a one-pass scan when compiling, that you implement the methods after the call site is the problem.

Either move the implementation or add this at the top of YourClass.m:

```
@interface YourClass()
- (void)rotate;
- (void)returnCar;
- (void)continueRotation;
@end
```

Comment: Anyone using Xcode 4.5 or later won't have this issue unless they have specifically changed the project's compiler setting. But this is a good point for those still using older compilers.

Comment: @maddy Thanks.  I wasn't sure which Xcode carried the compiler bits.